# Center div vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've got my CSS/HTML code [here](http://www.bootply.com/s2Au2qG0D7).

How do I align this so that it is vertically centered?

**HTML**

```
<div class="container" data-ng-controller="publicHome">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">// <--- I would like this div vertically centered!        
        <form data-ng-submit="signIn()" class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" data-ng-model="email" placeholder="email" class="form-control input-lg">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="password" data-ng-model="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control input-lg">
            </div>
            <label>
            remember me
            <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="rememberMe" class="signInCheckbox">
            </label>
            <div style="float:right; color:#C0C0C0;">
                <a data-ng-click="">forgot password?</a>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group center-block">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg center-block">sign in</button>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div class="alert alert-danger col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 text-center" role="alert">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> incorrect credentials
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.signInCheckbox {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

.forgotPassword {
    float: right;
    color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/114543/horizontally-center-a-div-in-a-div?rq=1

Comment: @Steve There is a very big difference between vertical and horizontal centering...

Comment: sry wrong one. this one should be it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div

Comment: @Steve I would know how to center a div normally, but since I am using bootstrap it is giving me unwanted results!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your div:

```
.customdiv {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate 0, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(0, -50%);
}
```

And this to your parent div:

```
.parentdiv {
    position: relative;
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yybnnL7p/)

Comment: Sorry, doesn't work with the example I posted :( (link)

Comment: Check out the FIDDLE in my Answer :)

Comment: Good answer if I wasn't using bootstrap, but it doesn't work as said with bootstrap for some reason!?

Comment: It's required to keep the "forgot password?" to the right side!

Comment: What div do you like to center?

Comment: I realized that you might be meaning another div than me, I updated the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the float right.

```
.forgotPassword {
    /* float: right; */
    color: #C0C0C0;
}
```

Maybe you were trying to do this?
https://jsfiddle.net/2jgrzqnh/

Comment: Updated my question to show which dive I was wanting centered vertically :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Add this CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

.signIn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate -50%, -50%);
    -o-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunetly it's not again, take a look: http://www.bootply.com/rKNvoqGu19 feel free to edit the code in the link :)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add two empty colums either side of your `.signIn` Div.

```
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-4 signIn">
   // your form here
  </div>
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
```

Bootstraps grid works on a basis that all the columns add up to 12. 
http://www.bootply.com/X19w9RZawU

Comment: I think you misread the topic, it's vertical positioning I'm trying to fix, not horizontal!

Answer (score 0):

The alert has a `margin-bottom: 20px`. The `<div>` at the top needs `margin-top: 20px`, so that the box is vertically centered.

**HTML**

```
...
<div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4 margin-top-20">
...
```

**CSS**

```
.margin-top-20 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ExvHLNQGOX)